# How to tell whether an invoked method has a method body or not at runtime in an Android app/Java application?

Tags: java, android, reflection

I hope to know if an invoked method has a Java method body at runtime in an Android app/Java application.

For example, in the following code, a method `f` is invoked

```
obj.f();
```

To know whether `f` has a method body, I use reflection to get its modifiers and then check if the method is a native method:

```
int modifiers = obj.getClass().getMethod("f", new Class[] {}).getModifiers();
if(Modifier.isNative(modifiers)) {
   // No method body
} else {
   // has method body
}
```

My question is: except native methods, are there any other possible cases in which an invoked method does not have a Java method body? Abstract or interface methods are not possible since at runtime, what have been invoked must be concrete methods that implement them.

Comment: This smells suspiciously like [an XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info). What underlying problem are you trying to solve with this knowledge? Also what counts as "having a Java method body?" Does `c.call()` have a method body if `c` is defined as `Callable c = System::gc`?

Comment: `abstract` methods don't have a body as well. And yes, `native` methods can implement abstract methods.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what good that information could do, so maybe I'm missing something.

But some of the cases that I can think of off the top of my head are

1. Objects created by [`java.lang.reflect.Proxy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html)
2. Lambdas such as `Callable c = System::gc`.
3. default methods on interfaces *may or may not* count, depending on your definition and use-case